# Unwanted offset in title \rule

Tags: titles, rules

I was trying to make a custom title layout, but the initial rule was getting slightly indented in a way that was not nice.

Here's a minimal example of what I was trying to do:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../resources/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \normalfont \normalsize
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
  \flushleft{\Huge\bfseries Company Name Ltd.}
  \hfill
  $
  \begin{array}{r}
    \includegraphics[trim = 4px 4px 4px 4px, clip,
      width=3cm]{dots}
  \end{array}
  $ \vspace{0.5cm}
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
  {\huge \bfseries Important Subtitle} \hfill {\bfseries \today}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

And the result: [image: slightly off title]

Notice how the ends of the two rules don't line up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a better control if you avoid a the mistake of using `\flushright` which exists only because the `flushright` environment does.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../resources/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\normalfont \normalsize \raggedright

\hrule height 1pt

\vspace{0.5cm}

{\Huge\bfseries Company Name Ltd.\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|@{}}
  \hline
  \includegraphics[trim = 4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt, clip, width=3cm]{dots}
  \\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\hrule height 1pt

\vspace{0.5cm}

{\huge \bfseries Important Subtitle} \hfill {\bfseries \today}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Note that issuing `\raggedright` avoids any problem with indents.

The command `\hrule` is a primitive one (so it has a strange syntax); it's better in cases like this because it doesn't start a paragraph and doesn't add unnecessary vertical spaces; but you can use `\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}` if you prefer, with some less easy control of vertical spacings.

The `tabular` (which is better than `array`) must be in the same scope as `\Huge` so the vertical centering has real effect. I added rules to the tabular just to better show the final disposition of the elements.

Don't use `px` without first having defined its size. It *doesn't* mean “pixels in the present image's units”.

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thanks for the explanations along with how it could be done differently.

Answer (score 2):

The solution: put a `\noindent` at the beginning.

Here's the final code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../resources/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \noindent
  \normalfont \normalsize
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
  \flushleft{\Huge\bfseries Company Name Ltd.}
  \hfill
  $
  \begin{array}{r}
    \includegraphics[trim = 4px 4px 4px 4px, clip,
      width=3cm]{dots}
  \end{array}
  $ \vspace{0.5cm}
  \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
  {\huge \bfseries Important Subtitle} \hfill {\bfseries \today}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

And the very pleasing result: [image: Good Title]